# .htaccess mod_rewrite, probably very simple

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to take my link domain.com/view.php?id=12345 and my it to be domain.com/view/12345

I'm unsure on to have I need to do, or what so here are my questions:

1. Do I need to make a view folder and put a file in there?
2. How would I make the rewrite rule?
3. How can I make it redirect to the new link?
4. What would I link my pages as?

Here is my current rewrite rule. I know it's using the file because I did a test earlier from anther questions I found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/$ view.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Is the code you showed not working? Or not working how you expected?

Comment: I thought it would redirect to what it should, but I guess I have to actually go to view/12345 instead of going to view.php Do you know how I would do questions 3, I answered question 4 myself.

Comment: I would take a look at this. I think it you can combine it with what you have somehow ... still working on how. http://digwp.com/2011/01/new-htaccess-permalink-rules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need a folder.
2. It's ok.
3. In view.php somewhere:

```
$filteredId = someFilterFunction($_GET['id']);
header('Location: /view/' + $filteredId);
```

But it's probably going to be an infinite redirect :) so don't do it. You should check the request url for example.

4 . I don't understand the question.

Comment: When I go to view.php?id=12345 it shows view.php?id=12345 instead of /view/12345

Comment: Yes, because rewrite is to make this extension less url: /view/12345 into view.php?id=12345 and not vica-versa. If you want to redirect the user to /view/12345 then that's a different thing

Comment: I added the questions 3 and 4. If you know, could you edit your answer?